# ng-class or ng-style for error message in text area validation

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I am wondering what the best "angular" approach would be for changing the style of the character count for validation.  I have a text area that is limited to 250 characters.  Instead of using the max-length we want to allow the user to enter more than 250 but display a negative number and change the style to the color red (like twitter, etc.).   The question is what is the best approach?   Use ng-style or ng-class with a boolean evaluation to make the change?

```
  <h6 class="subheader right" ng-class="{'alert':'(250 - formData.SubTitle.length)<0'}">{{250 - formData.SubTitle.length}} /250</h6>
```

"alert" is the class name to switch to once the number of characters entered < 0

**UPDATE:**
What is the difference between ng-class and ng-style in this case? (if any)

Comment: define `best` ... what you are doing makes sense to me. Should reallly only be asking if there is a problem

Comment: What you are doing seems ok

Comment: Right.  They seem to be the exact same thing but I am assuming there are subtle differences.  This is for a web app that is mobile friendly.

Comment: I edited the question to refine.

Comment: main difference is it's easier to maintain styles in a stylesheet and also easier to test for existence of a class than check specific css properties

Comment: Right.  So I see now why the Angular team included both.  nothing to do with Angular but with HTML/CSS.  I was reading into it too much ;)  Thanks.  - PS.  I disagree about your comment that I should only be asking if there is a problem.  There actually could have been a potential problem with a particular usage as there are in many languages.  Thanks for your time either way.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the application, it probably doesn't make much sense to use ng-style.  Particularly if your app has numerous inputs.  One class for them all makes much more sense and follows DNRY.  Adding styles to every single input is rather tedious.  Exponentially so when you suddenly have to make a change to 100 inputs (and you will...)